# Ideas for querying firebird (.fbd) database?

Tags: python, sql, database, firebird

We do have a software, where we document a lot of different info. The software stores all data in an .fdb database.

Unfortunately the reporting system in the software is very limited. The given reporting options often don't fit our needs. There is so much data stored, we could make use of.

E.g. In one part of the software we have stored our staff with lots of additional info. In another part we do store trainings that staff visited.

Two examples: 1. A (simplified) report that we would need (but don't have) would look like this: Look for all staff from department A, that has not participated in Training T1 in 2017. Print names from staff that needs training T1.

2. To have training T2 passed, 100hrs are needed. Training T2 is documented in software with time and date. Over several days in a years. Set time needed for T2=100 Look for all staff from dept. B that has done training T2 in 2017. Report staff from department B that has not done 100hrs training and print hours needed for each staff.

I'm asking here for some kind of brainstorming. What would be a tool or a programming language to learn to process our individual report needs. Recently fb has shown me some ads (udemy) about data mining and analysis with python, that's why I added it as a tag.

What would be a good start to look at and learn it?

Comment: These types of questions are explicitly off-topic on stack overflow

Comment: Maybe you should start with the same language that your main app is written in - that would 1) provide you with How-To's: you read your app sources and see how things are done. 2) provide you with enhancing the program with the features you would develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On desktop windows/native, Delphi integrates very well with Firebird. There are a lot of data access components and excellent reporting tools like FastReport and FastCube for OLAP analysis. Last one is great for custom user defined reports on the fly.

On Linux you may try Lazarus, there are tools like IBX & (Laz/Free)Report.

On web, it works well with ExtJS/PivotGrid with PHP as backend, at least we do it.

Probably it works nice with .NET and Java as it have ODBC/JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

A great solution is to setup an ODBC connection to Firebird and access the data using excel directly.  You can get the ODBC driver from firebirdsql.org.

For a more traditional reporting like experience try the following:
- Crystal reports (Paid with free trial)
- Pentaho's community edition reporting and data tools work great with Firebird.  http://community.pentaho.com/ (Free)